# python transitions library: How to pass argumnets to a transition?

Tags: python, transition, state-machine

Following the [documentation](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions) on github, it is not evident how to create a parameterized transition.

They define transitions like

```
self.machine.add_transition(trigger='wake_up', source='asleep', dest='hanging out')
```

And I want something like

```
self.machine.add_transition(trigger='wake_up_parameterized', source='asleep', dest='hanging out', ...)
```

where ... is somehow to pass the required parameters `wake_up_parameterized` would require.

Usage would be

```
batman.wake_up_parameterized(my_param1, my_param2)
```

Is that supported on Transisions?

If not, how do I go around this? Seems quite basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you reference, states:

> Sometimes you need to pass the callback functions registered at
>   machine initialization some data that reflects the model's current
>   state. Transitions allows you to do this in two different ways.
>
> First (the default), you can pass any positional or keyword arguments
>   directly to the trigger methods (created when you call
>   add_transition()
>   [...]
>   You can pass any number of arguments you like to the trigger.
>   There is one important limitation to this approach: every **callback**
>   function triggered by the state transition must be able to handle all
>   of the arguments. This may cause problems if the callbacks each expect
>   somewhat different data.

When changing states, work can be conducted in *callbacks*. `transitions` offers multiple occasions when callbacks can be invoked. From the documentation:

[image: Callback Execution Order]

The most common use case is to determine whether a transition should take place based on passed parameters. The right callback location for this is `conditions`. If more than one transition should be checked but data preprocessing is somewhat intensive, `prepare` can be used instead. For now, let's assume that only one transition should be checked.

```py
from transitions import Machine
import random


class Superhero:

    def world_is_in_danger(self, chocolate_bars, *args, **kwargs):
        return chocolate_bars < 3

    def business_hours(self, time, *args, **kwargs):
        return 9 < time < 17

    def restock(self, chocolate_bars, *args, **kwargs):
        new_stock = chocolate_bars + random.randrange(1, 4, 1)  # heroes cannot carry more than 3 bars at a time
        print(f"I am {self.state} and went to the store at {time}. The stock is now {new_stock}.")


hero = Superhero()
machine = Machine(model=hero, states=['resting', 'awake'], initial='resting')
machine.add_transition('call_for_help', 'resting', 'awake',
                       conditions=['world_is_in_danger', hero.business_hours],
                       after='restock')
hero.call_for_help(chocolate_bars=10, time=5)  # everything looks good
assert hero.state == 'resting'  # hero isn't moving a bit
hero.call_for_help(chocolate_bars=2, time=8)  # we are about to run out! but it's too early...
assert hero.is_resting()
hero.call_for_help(chocolate_bars=1, time=10, weather='sunny')  # someone must help us!
# >>> I am awake and went to the store at 10. The stock is now 3.
assert hero.is_awake()
```

As mentioned in the documentation, every parameter passed to a trigger function will be passed to **all** registered callbacks. The standard way to register callbacks is to pass them in `add_transition`. We passed two `conditions` callbacks: one as a string which is the standard way to do it and one as a function reference. Passing callbacks as strings will assume that our model (our hero) has a method (or will have a method at the time of calling) with that name. A function reference does not have to be assigned to the model in question. We also registered one callback for `after` which will be called, wenn the transition has been conducted. If we evaluate `hero.state` in that callback, it's already set to `awake`. By adding `*args` and `**kwargs` to our callback functions, we made sure that the callbacks are flexible enough to deal with a varying amount of passed parameters and only consider relevant information.